# Can't replace "," with newline in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, newline, tr

I already tried using `sed`, now I'm using `tr`,

```
list="banana, apple, orange, strawberry"

listed_text=$(echo $list| tr , '\n')
```

Desired output:

```
banana
apple
orange
strawberry
```

Output I get:

```
banana apple orange strawberry
```

I'm using zsh as shell, but I checked in bash and it also doesn't work. I tried \n, \n, tried an literal newline `"\ "` but it won't work. All I get is t that same single line output!

Comment: What do you mean by "actual output".  The commands you present would produce no output at all.  `echo "$listed_text"` should give you what you expect, however, while `echo $listed_text` would give you what you claim you are getting.

Comment: BTW, the proper bash way to store a list of things is in an _array_. If you used `IFS=', ' read -r -a items <<<"$list"`, then you'd have a proper list of your items; you could use `echo "Number of items is ${#items[@]}"` to count the entries; `echo "${items[0]}"` or `echo "$items"` to show only the first one, `printf '%s\n' "${items[@]}"` to print them all, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) (`tr` is not sufficient to remove leading space):

```
echo "$list" | sed 's/, /\n/g'
```